# Как проще взять данные с 5 td после каждой tr с помощью preg_match_all

Tags: php, html

В таблице с tr нет проблем достать значения, с помощью кода, ниже.

Например:

```
<tr data-vehicle-cd="10401"
```

Рабочий код:

```
$curl = curl_init();

$url = "-->source_link<--";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result =curl_exec($curl);
$account = array();

$pattern = '!<tr data-vehicle-cd="(.*?)"!';
preg_match_all($pattern, $result, $match);

$account = $match;
print_r($account);
```

Проблема в том, что все 5 td после tr имеют одинаковые классы.

Есть ли способ с каждой tr, брать значения с 5 td, она же последняя в каждой tr (5 из 5)?

каждая td выглядит так:

```
<td data-sort-value="2" data-hovered-class="table_cell-hover" class="">
```

Нужно взять значения после value="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмите все, потом из массива ту, что нужна.